# How to select nth row in mapbasic?

Tags: mapinfo, mapbasic

There are multiple rows in my .tab file in mapinfo. Is there any way to select nth row in mapbasic window of mapinfo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Select * from 'table' Where RowID = n`

If you want it into a selection table of your choice, put the selection `into somename`, then `browse * from somename`  If not, just `Browse from selection`

**edit**

This is all from memory, so please play about and also read the online reference manual:

[MapBasic Ref](http://reference.mapinfo.com/software/mapbasic/english/9_0/MB_UG.pdf)

[MapInfo -L](http://groups.google.com/group/mapinfo-l)

Comment: By the way, the help is ok.

Comment: nps. Seriously though, have a look at the help, as they'll give code samples, you can play with.  I'd also recommend 'MapInfo -l'.  It's sort of a way of searching through some cracking code samples.

Comment: yes I have the user guide I am studying but small things confuse me :(

Comment: well, nps, you'll get answers here as long as you accept them and act in good grace (which I fail to do sometimes).

Answer (score 0):

Very simple with Fetch:

Fetch rec 125 From Database

will find record #125 in your database...

Comment: Fetch will only set the cursor at that position and not "select" the actual row. But it does depend on what he wants to do with the row afterwards